# PHP- replace strings where they appear between two numbers

Tags: php, str-replace

I have strings that look like the following:

- 3/2 Johns St
- 3,2 Johns St
- 3 2 Johns St

I want to replace any occurance of `/`, `,` and  with a `\` when they appear in between 2 numbers.
So the above would all end up looking like `3\2 Johns St`.
What is the easiest way to do this with PHP?

Comment: do you mean "So the above would all end up looking like `3\3 Johns St.` What is the easiest way to do this with PHP?"

Answer (score 3):

Use `preg_replace('/(\d)[\/, ](\d)/', '$1\\\\$2', $string);`

Comment: `3$2 Johns St` was the output I get.

Comment: Then replace pattern should be `'$1\\\\$2'`

Comment: Works great. Thankyou. Can you explain how this only replaces the space, slash and comma? I don't know alot about regex, but can't see what specified in the first argument that we are looking for spaces, slashes and commas.

Comment: The first `(\d)` means "Match digit and remember as $1", `\D` means "Find anything, but digit", the second `(\d)` means "Find digit and remember as $2". Replacement pattern is "use $1, then backslash, then $2". At first I forgot to escape backslash and it resulted in "Replace to the first digit and '$2'". See http://www.regular-expressions.info/ to learn more about regex.

Comment: Thanks for the explanation. I just did a test and this replaced anything between the two numbers. I only want to replace it when its a slash, comma or space.

Comment: See edited version (`/(\d)[\/, ](\d)/`), square brackets mean "any character of"

Answer (score 0):

Try this :

```
$str  = '3/2 Johns St';
echo $str_new  = preg_replace('/(\d)([^\d])+(\d)/','$1\\\\$3',$str);
```